# Setting or not setting array value via Ternary Operation

Tags: php, ternary-operator

This is probably a silly question:

I am doing the following to set the headers in an array that I convert to a CSV download. The CSV part is irrelevant to this question as it works just fine.

Array Headers:

```
$csv_fields  = array();
$csv_fields[0]   = array();
$csv_fields[0][] = 'Category';
$csv_fields[0][] = 'Question';
$csv_fields[0][] = 'Case';
$csv_fields[0][] = 'Partner';
// ... etc
```

Now I want to set the heads based on check boxes that are `Posted` to the script. I was going to use lots of `if, else` statements like so:

```
if ($_POST['category']) {

    $csv_fields[0][] = 'Category';

elseif ($_POST['question']) {

    $csv_fields[0][] = 'Question';

}
// .... etc
```

But thought there might be a better way using **Ternary Operator**. I tried the following, but of course if the `$_POST` is not set, it still adds a null value to the array, so I get gaps in my headers.

```
$csv_fields[0][] = isset($_POST['category']) ? 'Category' : NULL;
// ... etc
```

I end up with something like:

```
[0] => 
[1] => Question
[2] => 
[3] => Partner
// ... etc
```

So my question is, how can I use the Ternary Operator to just skip rather than set the array value if the `$_POST` variable is not set?

Or is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: where is Partner Coming from?

Comment: It is just another header that I set. You can see I set it implicitly in my first block of code above. It is just an example. I didn't want to show my entire script as it is very clear what I am trying to do from the snippet. You should be able extrapolate out from it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a tenary operator could help you with this..
But you could shorten your code, because it's a lot of boilerplate and you could move everything to an loop.

```
$vars = array(
    'category' => 'Category',
    // ...
);

foreach ($vars as $name => $text) {
    if (isset($_POST[$name])) {
        $csv_fields[0][] = $text;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a winner. Can't believe I didn't reach this solution myself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ternary in combination with `array_merge()`.

```
$csv_fields[0] = array_merge($csv_fields[0], 
                             isset($_POST['category']) ?
                             array('Category') : array());
```

It's neither pretty or efficient. Better use a loop.